# Silverlight navigation application : How to catch exceptions at page level?

Tags: silverlight

We know that we can catch any unexpected exception at application level by using Application.Current.UnhandledException. Is there any way I can catch exceptions at page level rather than application level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. A page doesn't really have any particular scope of execution. You could very well have multiple pages on a given screen at any time. But in the Silverlight navigation application project template in Visual Studio there's a really stupid block of code that hides exceptions from you and turns them into useless "navigation failed" messages.

This is in the Frame.NavigationFailed event which is raised for exceptions while *navigating* to a particular page. But not exceptions that occur afterwards. If you want to access the exception, it's in the EventArgs.

```
private void ContentFrame_NavigationFailed( object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e )
{

    e.Handled = true;

    // the navigation template does this. useless
    //ChildWindow errorWin = new ErrorWindow( e.Uri );

    // this will show the exception
    ChildWindow errorWin = new ErrorWindow( e.Exception );

    errorWin.Show( );
}
```